# Convergent sums and rate of decay

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

True or False: If $a_n\in\ell^1,$ then $\overline{\lim}n a_n<\infty$ (i.e. $a_n=O(\frac{1}{n})$)

Edit: My intuition says the answer should be positive.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange.  This is a learning community, so we expect questions to include your thoughts/work with some specifics of where you are having trouble, please edit your question and add a few of these details so our help can be more targeted.

Answer (score 2):

This is false.  Consider the sequence $a_{n}=\frac{1}{i^2}$ if $2^{i}=n$ and $a_{n}=0$ otherwise.  $a_{n}\in \ell^{1}$ because summing it is (padded with zeros) the same as $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ which of course converges.  But $a_{n}n=\frac{2^{i}}{i^2}\to \infty$ whenever $n$ is a power of $2$.  So $\limsup na_{n}=\infty$.